# Expected a com.google.gson.JsonObject but was com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive

Tags: json, gson, retrofit2

Expected a com.google.gson.JsonObject but was com.google.gson.JsonPrimitive error occurred while testing with Android Studio.
Does anyone know what the problem is and how to solve it?

@Headers("Content-Type:application/json")
@POST("/order/additem")
fun doPostList(@Header("Authorization") token: String?, @Body dto: orderModel?): Call

data class orderModel(
@SerializedName("orderid")
var orderid:String?,
@SerializedName("ordername")
var ordername: String?,
@SerializedName("totalprice")
var totalprice: Int,
@SerializedName("paymentkey")
var paymentkey: String?,
@SerializedName("orderstate")
var orderstate: Int,
)

MainActivity.kt
val client = OkHttpClient()

```
                                    val mediaType = MediaType.parse("application/json")
                                    val qrBody = RequestBody.create(
                                        mediaType,
                                        "{\"paymentKey\":\"${success.paymentKey}\",\"amount\":$price,\"orderId\":\"$orderid\",\"customerName\":\"$customerKey\",\"orderName\":\"$ordername\"}"
                                    )

                                Log.w("zio","paymentkey : ${success.paymentKey}")
                                    val request = Request.Builder()
                                        .url("https://api.tosspayments.com/v1/payments/confirm")
                                        .header(
                                            "Authorization",
                                            "Basic dGVzdF9za19aT1J6ZE1hcU4zd015a1p5bDdOcjVBa1lYUUd3Og=="
                                        )
                                        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
                                        .post(qrBody)
                                        .build()

                                    val response = client.newCall(request).execute()

                                    val status = response
                                try {
                                    if(status.isSuccessful){

                                        Log.w("zio", "결제인증 성공")
                                        customDialogBinding =
                                            CustomDialogBinding.inflate(LayoutInflater.from(this@PayActivity))

                                        val paymentkey = success.paymentKey
                                        Log.w("zio","paymentkey2 : $paymentkey")

                                        val tokenSaved = getSharedPreferences("token", MODE_PRIVATE)
                                        val token = tokenSaved.getString("token",null)
                                        Log.w("zio","tosspayment_token : $token")

                                        val payRetrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                                            .baseUrl("https://api.format.kro.kr")
                                            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                                            .build();

                                        val jsonObject = JsonObject()
                                        jsonObject.addProperty("token",token)
                                        jsonObject.addProperty("orderid",orderid)
                                        jsonObject.addProperty("ordername",ordername)
                                        jsonObject.addProperty("totalprice",totalprice)
                                        jsonObject.addProperty("paymentkey",paymentkey)

                                        val dto = orderModel(orderid, ordername, totalprice, paymentkey,1)

                                        Log.w("zio","dto : $dto")

                                        val payService = payRetrofit.create(NetworkService::class.java)
                                        val postCall = payService.doPostList(token ,dto)

                                        postCall.enqueue(object : retrofit2.Callback<JsonObject> {
                                                override fun onResponse(
                                                    call: retrofit2.Call<JsonObject>,
                                                    response: retrofit2.Response<JsonObject>
                                                ) {
                                                    if(response.isSuccessful){
                                                        Log.w("zio","보내기 성공!!")

                                                    }else{
                                                        Log.w("zio","API 접속 실패 : ${response.code()}")
                                                    }
                                                }

                                                override fun onFailure(
                                                    call: retrofit2.Call<JsonObject>,t: Throwable) {
                                                    Log.w("zio", "전송실패: ${t.message}, ${t.printStackTrace()}")
                                                }
                                            })
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.